# Node.js + Express - can't make app as SPA working

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, single-page-application

Having troubles with making my app to work as a Single Page Application. I'm using pug as a template engine.

Here is a general structure of the app:

```
/app
/app/index.js // source of the app
/app/index.html
/app/bundledApp.js // from running webpack command
/app/components
/app/components/loginPage
/app/components/welcomePage
/app/config/routes.js
```

Here is my index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="bundledApp.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

index.js file:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const server = require('http').Server(app);
const port = 3000;

app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.use('/', routes);

server.listen(port, (err) => {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    console.log(':)');
});
```

router.js file:

```
const express = require('express');
const welcomePage = require('../components/welcomePage');
const login = require('../components/loginPage');
const router = express.Router();

router.route('/').get(welcomePage.welcomePage);
router.route('/login').get(login.loginPage);

module.exports = router;
```

### Failed approach number 1:

Tried to add in index.js:

```
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/'));
app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
```

but when I run the app I get in the console:

```
bundledApp.js:736 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

### Failed approach number 2:

I tried to use express-spa package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-spa), just required it in index.js and added:

```
app.use(spa());
```

but in the browser I get in the console while going to http://localhost:3000 :

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

in `bundledApp.js`

My pug file looks like this for welcomePage view:

```
extends ../mainLayout/mainLayout  // just a HTML5 template file

block title
    title Welcome Player!

block content
    a(href='/login') Go to login page
```

The app itself runs fine but I won't it to behave like a SPA page rather having pages being refreshed while going to different URLs. What am I missing in my approach?

Here is also a webpack.config.js file:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

let config = {
    entry: '/app/index.js',
    target: 'node',
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, '/app/index.js'),
        filename: 'bundledApp.js'
    }
};

module.exports = config;
```

Thanks for all the help guys! :)

Comment: Node.JS is a server-side technology, not a browser technology. Thus, Node-specific calls, like require(), do not work in the browser.

See browserify or webpack if you wish to serve browser-specific modules from Node.

Comment: I'm aware of this but don't know exactly how to configure Webpack to serve this.

Comment: Sammy js is great framework to build spa. Very simple, documented, and many more. Maybe this can you try

Answer (score 0):

You need to informe express where your files are using `express.static` as following:

`app.use(express.static("app"));`

More info [here](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html).